# Calculating number of con-consecutive total years donated in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have some sample donation history:

ID  TransactionDate Amount
10  2001-12-19 00:00:00.000 75.00
10  2001-07-11 00:00:00.000 760.00
10  2010-10-15 00:00:00.000 2200.00
10  2012-08-15 00:00:00.000 1220.00
10  2013-09-16 00:00:00.000 610.00
100 2000-09-26 00:00:00.000 3000.00
100 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000 5000.00

I am trying to get a summary of giving by year by donor. The total does not have to be for consecutive years, but will just total overall # of years given. The total does not need to equal the number of transactions per year, just that the ID donated in that particular year.

For instance, ID 10 above would equal 4 indicating giving in 4 calendar years (2 donations in 2001, 1 in 2010, 1 in 2012, and 1 in 2013). ID 100 would equal 2.

The donations date back many years, so hard-coding dates is not very feasible.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Thank you the comment below did not do exactly what I wanted but it led me to this solution which I think works: 

`SELECT ID,  
       SUM(CASE  
               WHEN count > 1  
               THEN 1  
               ELSE count  
           END)  
FROM  
(  
    SELECT ID,  
           DATEPART(yy, TransactionDate) Year,  
           COUNT(*) AS count  
    FROM tablename  
    GROUP BY ID,  
             DATEPART(yy, TransactionDate)  
) sub  
GROUP BY ID  
ORDER BY 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, DATEPART(yy,TransactionDate) Year, COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID, DATEPART(yy,TransactionDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return and then `group` on the relevant parts of your data, which is the `ID` and the `year` of the `TransactionDate`:

```
select d.ID
      ,count(1) as DonationYears
from(select distinct ID    -- Sub query returns one row per ID and Year, which is counted up by ID in the outer query
                    ,year(TransactionDate) as TranYear
     from Donations
    ) d
group by d.ID
```